# Type arguments [Nothing,X] do not conform to type parameter bounds [T,X<: XX[T]]>

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, scala-macros

I am trying to implement a macro which returns subtype of class `XX`, with type parameter `T`. The obvious implementation does not compile, probably because of Scala weak type inference.

Minimal example:

```scala
def foo[T, X <: XX[T]](x: X): X = macro fooMacro[T, X]

def fooMacro[T, X<: XX[T]](c: Context)(x: c.Expr[X]): c.Expr[X] = ...
```

Error message:

```
Error:(9, 11) macro implementation has incompatible shape: ...
type arguments [Nothing,X] do not conform to method fooMacro type parameter bounds [T,X<: XX[T]]>
```

Is it possible to work around this problem?

Comment: By the way, in Scala 3 type inference is improved: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/F0BlIsxtSRKFqfvocXVpIg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace type bound with implicit type constraint. The following code compiles

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

trait XX[_]

object Macro {    
  def foo[T, X](x: X)(implicit ev: X <:< XX[T]): X = macro fooMacro[T, X]

  def fooMacro[T: c.WeakTypeTag, X: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(x: c.Expr[X])(ev: c.Expr[X <:< XX[T]]): c.Expr[X] = {
    import c.universe._
    c.Expr(q"$x")
  }
}
```

*Type inference can be difficult ...* https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/9821

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/2272 (spoiler: *won't fix*)